# Data.Text vs. Rope

Tags: haskell

I've been looking into ropes as an alternative to Data.Text, and I like what I see so much that I am now *forced* to ask this question....  Is there *any* case where Data.Text would be the better choice?

Here are the points that lead me to this (correct me if I am wrong on any of these)-

1. A single leaf node rope internally *is* (almost) the same thing as a Data.Text object.  The overhead in a single node rope vs. text is minor, just a single bit flag to differentiate a branch or leaf.  If you really want Data.Text, just use an unsplit rope.
2. Complexity is universally equal or better in ropes- insert/delete (log(N) vs N), get by index (log(N)/N depending on depth of tree vs N).
3. I've read that the success of ropes proved to be a mixed bag in c, because performance was harmed by thread safety code.  However these concerns shouldn't matter in immutable Haskell.  In fact, it would seem to me that because of this, Haskell and ropes are ideal for each other.

Again, like in my previous similar questions, I am more interested in the abstract qualities of the structures, not the current situation (library usage, how hardened the code is, etc).  If you rewrote the Haskell libraries tomorrow, would you substitute Data.Rope for Data.Text?

Answer (score 8):

The "finger tree of packed arrays" seems like a good representation choice, although I would worry about constant overhead.  Some effort with aggressive stream fussion and some other optimizations for short strings might fix this, but `Data.Rope` lacks these features.  Right now `Data.Rope` is not really a `Data.Text` replacmenet.

1. It mainly implements strings of bytes not strings of charachters--it replaces byteString not text.  Unicode support is important.
2. Despite Edward's amazing-ness, Rope is not nearly as mature.  It hasn't had any contributions in a year, and is rarely used.
3. `Data.Text` has a huge engineering effort behind it, is highly optimized, and is well known and well documented

Comment: But these comments are all about implementation....  I am curious about the ideal Text vs. the ideal Rope.  What should we be striving towards as a community, great Rope and great Text, or just great Rope?

Comment: String of bytes vs string of characters is definitely *not* an implementation detail.

Comment: @Kata- No one is claiming it is....  I was saying that this answer was about the state of the current libraries, I am interested in the concepts independent of the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago when I tried to use Rope, the author told me it wasn't really usable yet, it was just an experiment. One problem with Hackage is the difficulty of learning which package/versions are really production-ready.

Is the Rope as Unicode-compatible as Data.Text ?